# Finding the length of $BC$ in a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

[image]

Calculate the length of $BC$.

I first started by letting $M$ the point of intersection of $AC$ and $DB$. Now $MB^2+MA^2 = 9$, $MD^2+MA^2 = 16$, $MD^2+MC^2 = 36$. Therefore, $BM^2+MC^2 = BC^2$

Can someone please help me with proceeding as I am stuck. Thanks.

Comment: The title is misleading, a kite has a pair of equal adjacent sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$(MB^2+MA^2)-(MD^2+MA^2)+ (MD^2+MC^2) = MB^2+ MC^2$$

Comment: I am not sure what you did there to reach that step. Can you please explain it?

Comment: Do you agree with $(b+a)-(d+a)+(d+c)=b+c$ for any numbers $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: That's all I'm saying for the squares of the segments. Then, you have already computed the bracketed terms on the left hand side of the equality, while for the right hand side you've shown that it is equal to $BC^2$.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks.

Comment: @AspiringMathlete In geometry, kite is a reserved word. Certain characteristics must be satisfied before the figure can be called a kite. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite_%28geometry%29. Of course, you can still use it loosely as a common word.